# Blazor Components: How can I have a different ComponentBase?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I would like to link a Blazor component to my own ComponentBase but I get the error

**Partial declarations of 'TestComponent' must not specify different base classes**

Is this actually possible? Here are my examples.

```
@* TestComponent.razor *@
<h3>Test Component</h3>
```

```
// TestComponent.razor.cs
public partial class TestComponent : MyComponentBase
{}
```

```
public class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
   public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate if you'd mark my answer as accepted if so, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but you need to also specify the base class in `TestComponent.razor` like so:

`@inherits MyComponentBase;`